# Woes using UPDATE with a CTE in MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb, common-table-expression

I'm going crazy trying to get UPDATE to work with a CTE in MySQL.

Here's a simplified schema of `sa_general_journal`:

```
CREATE TABLE `sa_general_journal` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Transaction_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'NULL if not split, same as ID for split records',
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
…
  `Statement_s` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
…
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
…
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
…
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25929 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Some records are "split," for example, a credit card statement amount might have a sales tax amount that is split out. In such cases, both parts of the split record have the same ID in the Transaction_ID field.

When records are imported in bulk, they can't refer to `last_insert_ID` in order to fill in the Transaction_ID field, thus the need to go clean these up afterward.

This was my first, naive attempt, which said I had an error near `UPDATE`. Well duh.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        MIN(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY `Date`, `Name`, Statement_s) AS Trans,
        Transaction_ID
    FROM sa_general_journal
    WHERE Transaction_ID = 0)
UPDATE cte
SET Transaction_ID = Trans
```

The CTE itself seems to work, as I can follow it with `SELECT * FROM cte` and get what I expected.

So I started searching StackOverflow, and discovered that CTEs are not updatable, but that you need to join them to what you want to update. "No problem!" I think, as I code this up:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        MIN(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY `Date`, `Name`, Statement_s) AS Trans,
        Transaction_ID
    FROM sa_general_journal
    WHERE Transaction_ID = 0)
UPDATE sa_general_journal gj, cte
SET gj.Transaction_ID = cte.Trans
WHERE gj.ID = cte.ID
```

No joy. Same error message.

My understanding is that in MySQL, you don't need a column list, but I did also try this using the column list `(a, b, c)`, with the proper columns referenced in the `UPDATE` statement, but it still said I had a problem near `UPDATE`.

There are incredibly few examples of using `UPDATE` with `WITH` on the Internet! I found one, [from Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/10/introduction-to-mysql-8-0-common-table-expressions-part-1/), which I used to create my attempt above, and then found another very similar example [from MySQL itself](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88397).

Thanks in advance for any help offered!

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, both before and after the update.  This will help you to get an answer faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I no longer have any "before" data, thanks to @Akina, who provided the solution, below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CTE is a part of subquery definition, not a part of the whole query. The query must be specified after CTE. CTE cannot be used itself. So

```
UPDATE sa_general_journal gj
JOIN (WITH cte AS ( SELECT
                         ID,
                         MIN(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY `Date`, `Name`, Statement_s) AS Trans,
                         Transaction_ID
                    FROM sa_general_journal
                    WHERE Transaction_ID = 0)
      SELECT * FROM cte) subquery ON gj.ID = subquery.ID
SET gj.Transaction_ID = subquery.Trans
```

Comment: Thank you! 

I need to get used to thinking inside-out, I guess! 

BTW: I based my query on one suggested by the MySQL team: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88397

Comment: In looking over your solution, it occurs to me that a CTE is not actually needed at all, is it? ```cte``` is not referenced anywhere in your solution. Can't I get rid of everything inside the ```subquery``` parentheses, except for the actual ```SELECT``` statement? Not being critical; just trying to learn! :-)

Comment: @JanSteinman *it occurs to me that a CTE is not actually needed at all, is it?* Of course. The answer has a purpose to show how-to, not to solve.

Comment: "The answer has a purpose to show how-to, not to solve." No worries. It did both! I was bold, and just ran your query — knowing I had a backup. But the engineer in me wants to optimize it now. :-)

Answer (score 4):

CTEs work with UPDATE in MySQL 8, but not MariaDB 10.x.

Comment: sadly i can confirm that, not sure why it doesn't work

Comment: It's just not implemented, not much you can do.

Comment: CTE works with UPDATE in MariaDB 10.11, I have tried with success using @Akina's solution